# SortedMap Loses it's Order when converted into a Regular Map - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I've just noticed this strange behavior. So here I have two maps. One Sorted, and the other is a Regular one. When I try to add those pairs from **Sorted** one into the **Regular** one, then they **loses** their order? Is this normal, and if it is, then how not to lose that specified order when converting a sorted map into a regular one.

*NOTE: I'm working with Compose, so that's why I need `mutableStateMapOf()`*

```
private val sortedMap = mapOf(
    1 to "One",
    2 to "Two",
    3 to "Three"
).toSortedMap(reverseOrder())

private val regularMap = mutableStateMapOf<Int, String>()

fun sortMyMap() {
    sortedMap.forEach {
        Log.d("Map_Sorted", "${it.key}")
        Log.d("Map_Sorted", it.value)
    }
    sortedMap.forEach {
        regularMap[it.key] = it.value
    }
    regularMap.forEach {
        Log.d("Map_Regular", "${it.key}")
        Log.d("Map_Regular", it.value)
    }
}
```

Logs

```
Map_Sorted               D  3
Map_Sorted               D  Three
Map_Sorted               D  2
Map_Sorted               D  Two
Map_Sorted               D  1
Map_Sorted               D  One
Map_Regular              D  1
Map_Regular              D  One
Map_Regular              D  2
Map_Regular              D  Two
Map_Regular              D  3
Map_Regular              D  Three
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is working as designed. Why would you expect a non-sorted map to have any specific order? There is no contract specifying that insertion order should be respected during iteration on `mutableStateMapOf`.

Actually we can even go further and really read the contracts: `mutableStateMapOf` returns a `SnapshotStateMap`. The [doc of this type of map](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/snapshots/SnapshotStateMap) reads:

> This class closely implements the same semantics as HashMap.

And then the doc of [HashMap](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-hash-map/) reads:

> This implementation makes no guarantees regarding the order of enumeration of keys, values and entries collections.

So it's even made explicit that the implementation doesn't make any order guarantees.

Now about your follow-up question:

> Is this normal, and if it is, then how not to lose that specified order when converting a sorted map into a regular one

Losing order is exactly what this conversion means. But technically maps are not essentially meant to be iterated, they are dictionary data structures that allow accessing values by their keys. Some specific implementations of maps add some guarantees about order (like `SortedMap` or `LinkedHashMap`), but this is not the default. If you want an ordered thing to iterate, you should consider a `List` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info. But I still think it's confusing when I enter the sortedMap forLoop to see an unordered pairs.

Comment: Why do you say that? The `sortedMap.forEach` is definitely ordered, you can see that the items are printed in descending order as you specified

Comment: Oh yeah, my bad. So now it means that we cannot use a sorted map directly with a mutableStateMapOf API. I mean it will not work, because the sort will be lost.

Comment: but is there an alternative type of map that allows us to store state and is also ordered?